# How does metric decide if set is open or closed?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

I have a problem in which I am to decide if $A \subset (X,d)$ is open or closed.
There are two subproblems,  in which the set $A$ is the same but the metrics are different. My question is how does the metric "influence" if the set is open or closed?

My notion of a metric is that is some kind of "distance" function inherent to the set but I'm having a hard time seeing how this affects open and closedness. I guess my question is very general.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: write down the definitions of open and closed sets

Comment: The metric tells you which points are close to each other. A set is open if, when it contains a point $x$, it also contains all points "sufficiently close" to $x$.

Comment: A set is open if we can find a $\epsilon$-neighbourhood of space around every point in the set. And the set is closed if it is not open.

Comment: The metric determines basic open sets.

Comment: A set is open if it contains an $\epsilon$-ball around any of its points. Two different metrics do not necessarily induce different open sets. There can be distinct but topologically equivalent metrics.

Comment: Do you have **any** definition of open or closed sets? If you have it you could reformulate that using metrics instead. The problem with different metrics are easily solved by the fact that they may result in different topologies (ie a set can be open according to one metric and not according to another). How do you define your $\epsilon$-neighborhood? I'd guess that's all points closer than the distance (which is what the metric determines) $\epsilon$ to the point. BTW your definition of closed is wrong.

Comment: Open sets in a metric space are precisely the unions of balls w.r.t. that metric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define openness (as your book almost certainly does) in terms of the metric:

> A set $A \subseteq X$ is *open* if, for every $a \in A$, there is some real $r > 0$ such that the ball of radius $r$ (as measured by $d$), centered at $a$, is contained in $A$.

The general idea is that a set is open if no point in it is "right on the edge," i.e., around every point is at least little neighborhood of points still in the set, as measured by the metric. (A closed set is one whose complement (i.e., the set of everything outside it) is open.)

Answer (score 0):

A set is open if for every point in the set there exists $\epsilon-ball$, with $\epsilon > 0$ such that all points lying in this ball belong to the set. Metric is used to determine which points lie in this $\epsilon-ball$. For example on real line with usual distance the set {1,2,3} is not an open set because these are just points and regions around each point contain points that are not included in the set. But if we define the metric(you are right this corresponds to distance with particular properties) as $d(x,y)=1$ if $x \neq y$ and $d(x,y)=0$ if $x = y$, then the same set becomes an open set, because for any $\epsilon <1$ the $\epsilon-ball$ around a point $x$ contains only the point $x$ so all points in the $\epsilon-ball$ are included in the set.